# Language naming changed in iOS 9?

Tags: ios

I recently discovered that iOS 9 changed the values a pre-existing API returns, as far as current language setting is concerned. See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2418/_index.html).

As far as I understand, any app relying on a value returned by API `NSLocale.preferredLanguages()`, and correctly working on iOS 8, may fail on iOS 9.

Does anyone know if there is something that can be done to avoid the effects of this OS backward incompatibility, beside fixing and re-publishing any such app? Any configuration that the user may change on his/her iPhone, for instance?

**EDIT**: My apps were built for iOS 7, and relied on strings returned by the mentioned API in order to choose the language to use when querying the server's web services for contents to show. The criterion is very simple: "it" -> "it", "*any other*" -> "en". Now the API returns "it-IT" and this is considered "*any other*" by my apps. All my apps are broken; their UI is displayed in the correct language, but they show English contents instead of Italian contents.

I am perfectly aware that I can solve this trouble by modifying the code and re-publishing all my apps. In the long term I will, and I perfectly know how to do it (although the idea of re-publishing is a real nightmare). So thank you for the kind suggestions, but honestly I will not "accept" any "change-your-code" solution. My question was clear, I think, since it said "*beside fixing and re-publishing*".

Comment: if you have control over the web services, manage it on the server, so you don't have to publish the app again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This change should not break your existing application on iOS 9 if it was built with older SDK version.

To have it fixed for future (building with Xcode 7/ SDK 9.X), you need to give the support in your code. You can add a category on `NSLocale` something like this:

```
@implementation NSLocale (Addition)

+ (NSString *)myPreferredLanguage {
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"9.0")) {
        return [[[NSLocale preferredLanguages] firstObject] componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"][0];
    } else {
        return [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] firstObject];
    }
}
```

Where:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)  ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
```

Comment: It was built for iOS 7. It is broken. In more details: When the app queries the server's web services for contents, it also sends the language ID for the contents to be retrieved. The criterion is very simple: if the phone is set in Italian, ask for Italian content, otherwise ask for English content.

Comment: I believe, then, you will have to rebuilt & reship your app. I don't think there is any run time fix for this.